# JIRA: XSRF check failed

Tags: apache-2.2, jira

I recently setup a JIRA and Confluence site for company use. The Confluence site works great but the JIRA website throws the error "Error creating project, XSRF check failed" every time you try to create a project. I checked at: https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=397083076

It said unblock certain headers but, unfortunately, I am pretty new to the system administration side of things and wasn't sure exactly what they meant. I did some Googling and couldn't really find anything about it. For reference I am running RHEL 6.7, Apache 2.2, JIRA 6.4.11 and have it set up as a proxy in a virtual host to the express installation of JIRA.

The logs also don't mention anything useful as far as I can tell but if you want log/conf text then I can provide it as needed. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Have you raise an Atlassian.Support Case? They are pretty good.

Comment: @t1nt1n I was holding off from it but I just submitted a ticket. Probably not a bad idea to start working with them since I will be doing that for the rest of the lifespan of this website :> Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attlassian official answer:

https://tx-cac.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=397083076

It is highly possible that your proxy blocks some of headers. Try accessing jira directly (without proxy).

Also, it is possible that JIRA's security system does not like that your JIRA has different ports and hosts on apache and on internal instance. For his, Jira has special proxy options. There is even a special instrunction on apache:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/integrating-jira-with-apache-185729645.html

As for headers - those are special fields in HTTP request which help dealing with authorisation, encoding, languages and etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields